# Acessar todas as configurações do arquivo .env

Tags: laravel-5

alguém sabe como posso acessar todos os dados que estão no arquivo .env?, preciso trazer todos os dados como um array, já usei a função helper env(), sem sucesso, preciso de algo como o exemplo abaixo.

```
$dadosConn = [
'driver' => 'postgres',
'username' => '',
'password' => '',
'host' => '',
'database' => '',
'port' => ''];
```

Comment: Desculpe a pergunta, mas no .env não tem muitos dados que seriam úteis ao meu ver, qual o motivo exatamente?

Comment: Preciso acessar justamente os dados de conexão para depois usa-los para gerar relatórios usando a biblioteca JasperPHP.
Então seria legal se eu pudesse acessar os dados de conexão diretamente do .env.

Comment: O que `getenv('APP_ENV')` retorna?

Comment: retorna:

`"local"`

Answer (score 2):

Bem,  na verdade, você poderia resolver o problema usando o recurso interno usado pelo `Laravel 5`. Trata-se de uma biblioteca (que já vem instalada no `Laravel 5`) chamad `Dotenv`.

Veja como usar:

```
$dot = new Dotenv\Dotenv(base_path());
dd($dot->load());
```

O resultado é:

```
array:20 [▼
  0 => "APP_ENV=local"
  1 => "APP_DEBUG=true"
  2 => "APP_KEY=PzWPA7lYetAsN9aGmHuSsdVaNh7DfCjt"
  3 => "APP_URL=http://localhost"
  4 => "DB_HOST=127.0.0.1"
  5 => "DB_DATABASE=homestead"
  6 => "DB_USERNAME=homestead"
  7 => "DB_PASSWORD=secret"
  8 => "CACHE_DRIVER=file"
  9 => "SESSION_DRIVER=file"
  10 => "QUEUE_DRIVER=sync"
  11 => "REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1"
  12 => "REDIS_PASSWORD=null"
  13 => "REDIS_PORT=6379"
  14 => "MAIL_DRIVER=smtp"
  15 => "MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io"
  16 => "MAIL_PORT=2525"
  17 => "MAIL_USERNAME=null"
  18 => "MAIL_PASSWORD=null"
  19 => "MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null"
]
```

As informações são retornadas dessa forma, pois as mesmas não foram feitas para ser usadas como `array`, e sim para serem usadas pela função `getenv`. O `Dotenv` internamente usa a função `putenv`, para salvar as informações do arquivo `.env`.

Comment: Obrigado pela explicação.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode tentar isto:

```
var_dump(getenv('DB_HOST'));
var_dump(getenv('DB_DATABASE'));
var_dump(getenv('DB_USERNAME'));
var_dump(getenv('DB_PASSWORD'));
```

Se quiser colocar em um array ficará assim:

```
$dadosBanco = [
    'host'     => getenv('DB_HOST'),
    'database' => getenv('DB_DATABASE'),
    'username' => getenv('DB_USERNAME'),
    'password' => getenv('DB_PASSWORD')
];
```

Não trabalho muito com Laravel, mas acho você poderia configurar no arquivo `config/database.php`, o que seria o mais indicado. Lá você pode criar *múltiplas* configurações de conexão. Vai depender da necessidade.

Comment: Na verdade eu gostaria de usar de alguma forma a helper env(), atualmente eu consigo capturar todas as minhas configurações de conexão, entretanto gostaria de algo mais "elegante".

Comment: @geekcom "elegante" pode ter muitas interpretações, você pode criar uma classe ou qualquer coisa do genero, mas o importante é conseguir fazer o básico, se quer "enfeitar depois" já é uma escolha sua, procure se desprender um pouco disso e entender o nível mais baixo, depois você cria objetos, arrays, classes, etc. Veja um exemplo "com Array" que adicione ;)

Answer (score -1):

Só utilizar o `getenv()` ele já retorna direto todos os valores em um Array. Se quiser pegar só alguns valores recomendo pegar um por vez fazendo a pesquisa no `getenv({variável env})`.

fonte para mais informações: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.getenv.php

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

No framework Laravel se você está querendo usar o valor de uma variável do arquivo .env e está retornando nulo, precisa limpar o cache de configurações com o seguinte comando abaixo:

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Assim que executar esse comando faça o teste que se a variável tiver um valor ela não vai retornar nulo.